# Java SWT: MouseMove Event not working when it's dragged from another component

Tags: java, widget, swt, mouseevent, custom-controls

Currently I am working on open source project that create skeletal animation.

I created animation panel slider like in Adobe Flash in SWT.

Every slider in panel is child of `SWT Canvas` and each slider's frame is just drawn by`Graphics`.
Every slider and frame has it's own index.

`SWT.MouseMove` event works as expected when it's not dragged from another component, as you can see in the following code:

```
addListener(SWT.MouseMove, (e) -> {
                if(index == 4)
                System.out.println("this is my clicked frame:"+clickFrameIndex);
```

That will printing `this is my clicked frame: 9` when I doing this:

[image]

That's because it's clicked and then dragged in same slider (it's index is 4).

But when `SWT.MouseMove` event dragged from another component like this

[image]

from `slider index 1` to `slider index 4` it's not working anymore and that why only `slider index 1` get selected.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want. The listener is only called when the mouse is inside the control with the listener unless you call `setCapture` on the control.

Comment: @greg-449 yeah... thanks. tit's works now